# How change Time pickers icon color in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I need to change the default icon colour in Time pickers. but I don't know the way. If you can help me with this, It's really mean to me. Changes can see the below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the class `css-i4bv87-MuiSvgIcon-root`:

```
.css-i4bv87-MuiSvgIcon-root{
  color: red;
}
```

You can check this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictimepicker-material-demo-forked-6p2st?file=/style.css:0-46)